# smooth scroll only working on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

**UPDATE 2**

**I finally got the code to work but it only works within the same page. What should i do to make it work from a different page? I have the same links in every page and when a visitor on page 5 clicks X link, it should direct to the X anchor which is on page 2.**

**I've used Marius P.'s script which can be found down below.**

**[Here's my test page](http://hakanbaykul.com/smoothscrolltest/denemejsfiddlejump.html)**

No matter how much i've tried, the smooth scroll scripts are just not working for me. After many tries, i've tried to make a jsfiddle to see if the problem is from my script not loading. But nope. Even on jsfiddle my code is not working. It just jumps

Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/8H2sn/2/

and here is where i got the code from http://jsfiddle.net/YtJcL/

and here is my html just to satisfy stackoverflow

```
<div id="container">
<a class="scroll" href="#anchor1">go1</a>
<a class="scroll" href="#anchor2">go2</a>
<a class="scroll" href="#anchor3">go3</a>


<div id="anchor1"></div>
<div id="anchor2"></div>
<div id="anchor3"></div>
</div>
```

So what gives? Should i modify the script code? I am and will remain a js noob so i'm in the cold here. Any hint would be appreciated.

and if you say it's because of the css, then i'm screwed royally because that css must stay.

Comment: You didn't include the JQuery library in your fiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/8H2sn/3/

Comment: your JSFIDDLE works fine, you just need to add jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You have not included **jQuery** in the Fiddle. See top left under the heading 'Frameworks and Extensions'

Use the drop down to add the latest jQuery.

Comment: Sorry i didn't realize i had to do that. It works on fiddle now but still not working on the real site. What am i doing wrong? http://hakanbaykul.com/smoothscrolltest/denemejsfiddle.html

Comment: @SunBro I'm not quite sure off the top of my head, but try wrapping your script in this: `$(window).load(function(){` put-your-script-here `});`

Comment: But how will it call the class "scroll then" ?

Comment: @SunBro You don't need to change your HTML, just the JS at the top, add the line `$(window).load(function(){` before the script and `});` afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

You Javascript code is being run before the html elements are loaded. Make it wait for the document to be ready before execution by surrounding it with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".scroll").click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         //calculate destination place
         var dest=0;
         if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
              dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
         }else{
              dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
         }
         //go to destination
         $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1000,'swing');
     });
});
```

Also, you might run into troubles by using `this.hash` in your code instead of just `this` depending on your link type.